# Merkeling in Ethereum

Tags: merkle-patricia-tries, merkleization

I am currently facing the challenge to prove that a transaction is mined into a block.

Dose anyone know libraries/tools that do this kind of thing? e.g.: create a proof that can be validated offline etc.

I would appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the official [`go-ethereum`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/tree/master/trie) repository there are some Go files that are used by the client to construct tries and generate proofs with them. You can find them under `trie.go` and `proof.go` I believe and both also have their respective tests in the same directory so you can understand how they are used.

You can use these yourself offline to generate proofs and verify them.

Alternatively you can use [eth-proof](https://github.com/zmitton/eth-proof/issues) a Javacript library that can generate and verify proofs offline. I had some issues with this though and it didn't generate correct proofs all the time so be wary of this library.