# Get proof that a transaction was included within a block

Tags: transactions, merkle-patricia-tries, proof, proof-of-existence

I see that the web3 api has the `getProof` method: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html#getproof

My question is - is there a similar way to get (and verify) a proof that a transaction x is within a block y? Similar to BTC's `gettxoutproof` (http://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/gettxoutproof)?

Comment: you can use [eth_getTransactionByBlockHashAndIndex](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_gettransactionbyblockhashandindex) provided that you know block hash and index of the transaction.

Comment: yes, sorry for not clarifying, but I would like to get the Merkle proof of the transaction

Comment: Related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/56946/merkeling-in-ethereum